# How to know if intent is coming from 2 activities after current activity?

Tags: android

I have 3 Activities:

> Activity A --> Activity B (No History) --> Activity C

Activity A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ActivityB.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentKey.ActivityB);
```

Activity B:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, IntentKey.ActivityC);
```

or there is a Back button to call this method:

```
finish();
```

Activity C:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("test", "fromActivityC");
setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

Activity A:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    // Only returns from Activity B, never from C
}
```

Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: Post your `onActivityResult ` in Activity B.

Comment: Is it useful to have it? Since I set Activity B as No History

Comment: It is necessary to have it. Your activity C does not know how was Activity B launched. So it'll call `onActivityResult ` of B.

Comment: I have tried to put it in Activity B but it's not called

Answer (score 0):

Since you are starting Activity C for result from Activity B, Activity C will only call `onActivityResult()` for Activity B.

Same goes for Activity A. Since you are starting Activity B for result from Activity A, Activity B will only call `onActivityResult()` for Activity A.

You need call `setResult()` in Activity B for the `onActivityResult()` in Activity A to be called.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `ActivityC` does not know about `ActivityA` and `onActivityResult()` will be called only when you set result from `called` activty using `setResult()` method.

In `ActivityA`, method `onActivityResult()` will be called only if you set `result` from `ActivityB`.

So, you need to get the value of `test` in `onActivityResult()` of `ActivityB` and send this `value` to `ActivityA` using `intent` with `setResult()` method.

**ActitvityB**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data.getExtras() != null) {
        String str = data.getStringExtra("test");

        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
        returnIntent.putExtra("test", str);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
    }
}
```

Get the value of `test` from `ActitvityB`.

**ActitvityA**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (data.getExtras() != null) {
        String str = data.getStringExtra("test");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ActivityA onActivityResult() called value is: " + str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```